# Why can't I get the correct value from this node?

Tags: c++, pointers, tree

I am trying to reproduce a problem in my more complex code with a very simple code (as follows) which creates a tree and assigns keys, then traverses the tree and prints out the keys.

The output of this program should be give:

```
This key is 3
This key is 1
```

but instead it gives

```
This key is 3
This key is 33603600
```

which makes me think I am incorrectly creating my tree structure. Can anyone point out my mistake and hopefully critique my manner of creating this tree structure?

node.h:

```
  1 #ifndef _NODE_H_
  2 #define _NODE_H_
  3
  4 class node {
  5
  6   public:
  7     node();
  8     void assign(int keyval);
  9     int key();
 10     node* gt();
 11     node* lt();
 12
 13   private:
 14     node* _lt;
 15     node* _gt;
 16     int _key;
 17 };
 18
 19 // traverse the tree
 20 void traverse(node* pnode);
 21
 22 #endif
```

node.cpp:

```
  1 #include "node.h"
  2
  3 #include <stdio.h>
  4 #include <stdlib.h>
  5 using namespace std;
  6
  7 // default constructor
  8 node::node() {
  9   printf("Constructing node!\n");
 10   // start off as a leaf which returns no class
 11   _lt = NULL;
 12   _gt = NULL;
 13   _key = -1;
 14 }
 15
 16 // assign this key and create new nodes (if possible)
 17 void node::assign(int key) {
 18   printf("assigning key = %i!\n", key);
 19
 20   _key = key;
 21
 22   if(_key < 0) {
 23     return;
 24   }
 25   int key_lt = key-4;
 26   int key_gt = key-2;
 27   printf("key_lt = %i\n", key_lt);
 28   printf("key_gt = %i\n", key_gt);
 29   if( key_lt > 0) {
 30     node lt_node;
 31     lt_node.assign(key_lt);
 32     _lt = &lt_node;
 33   }
 34   if( key_gt > 0) {
 35     node gt_node;
 36     gt_node.assign(key_gt);
 37     _gt = &gt_node;
 38   }
 39 }
 40
 41 // simple return functions
 42 int node::key() {
 43   return _key;
 44 }
 45 node* node::gt() {
 46   return _gt;
 47 }
 48 node* node::lt() {
 49   return _lt;
 50 }
 51
 52 // traverse a node
 53 void traverse(node* pnode)
 54 {
 55   ///// same things!
 56   //printf("This key is %i\n", (*pnode).key());
 57   //printf("This key is %i\n", pnode->key());
 58   printf("This key is %i\n", pnode->key());
 59
 60   if(pnode->gt() != NULL) {
 61     pnode = pnode->gt();
 62     traverse( pnode );
 63   }
 64
 65 }
```

and finally, the main routine:

```
  1 #include "node.h"
  2
  3 #include <stdio.h>
  4
  5 using namespace std;
  6
  7 int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  8
  9   node* root = new node();
 10
 11   int key = 3;
 12   root->assign(key);
 13
 14   traverse(root);
 15 }
```

Comment: Could someone please critique my question if you are giving me downvotes so that I can write better questions next time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with how you are creating the `lt` and `gt` nodes in `node::assign()`. You are creating them on the stack, so the objects will be destroyed once execution leaves the scope they were created in.

You should allocate them on the heap (using `new`, like in `main()`, and delete them in the `node` destructor. Preferably, if you are using a compiler that supports C++11, you could consider using smart pointers (such as `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`) instead, so the nodes will be destroyed when they are no longer used.

In addition, `root` in `main()` is never destroyed. You should delete it after calling `traverse()` (or use a smart pointer). At least in your sample code, it isn't necessary to allocate it with `new` since it is only used within `main()`.